# Lord of the Rings Sound Design

Tags: sound-design

Im wondering how they create the sound when frodo puts on the ring and disappears this may sound easy but any ideas how they did it?

Answer (score 1):

"this may sound easy"

I dont remember much of those films - I went to screenings but it was a long time ago & I had no other involvement so take these comments with a grain of salt.... but I will say this: I sincerely doubt it was easy - Dave Farmer, Dave Whitehead & Brent Burge all probably contributed/discussed/shaped design elements for it ... and then Chris Boyes would have predubbed it to stems, then it would have been mixed in context alongside Mike Hedges & Michael Semanicks work, with many revisions to picture & to balance & element choices.... 
A lot, as in a LOT of evolution will have occurred in creating the contributing elements & a lot of mix evolution will have occurred in finding the best dramatic shape for that moment... Easy is not a word I would use, but like all great design in hindsight it might appear so

Comment: reiterating: I have no memory of the sound you describe, and have no intention of rewatching the films so take my comments philosophically, not literally

Answer (score 0):

I would like to echo Tim's sentiment here. I watched nearly every sound feature on those movies, and easy would not come up in my description. In order to make Treebeard's voice more convincing, they built in enormous wouldn't baffle to worldize. They also built another huge structure to dangle logs from to make his walking sound. Whenever easy comes up in Sound design, it's really always thinking about it comparatively. Sort of like "oh, that was easier than I thought it would be". With that being said, they do have a ton of features on the sound, check out on YouTube. I don't remember your sound coming up, but it may at least give you some insight into how they thought and approached things.

Much luck in your search.

Answer (score 0):

Have a search on YouTube for "lord of the rings sound design". There is a behind the scenes video for each of the three films, specicifically regarding the sound. If I remember correctly, in one of them is a whole section about how they did the sound for the ring. They're great videos anyway, so watch them all!